# Denegar permiso a los usuarios excepto al compilador C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

Estoy realizando una aplicación con un pequeño modulo muy básico de autoprotección a nivel de seguridad de usuario pero no se como quitarle el permiso al usuario actual que no escriba en la carpeta pero que si lo haga la aplicación, ejemplo: para eliminar la autoprotección el programa escribe en el archivo de configuración el estado del `checkbox` de autoprotección, si el `checkbox` esta habilitado se activaran los permisos, si lo deshabilita el usuario desde la interfaz del programa se inhabilitaran los permisos. Consegui un código pero a la hora de escribir en el programa le quita los permisos hasta a la aplicación.

```
private void HAutoproteccion_OnChange(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    configFile.AppSettings.Settings["Check3"].Value = Convert.ToString(HAutoproteccion.Checked);
    configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    Autoproteccion();
}


public void autoproteccion(){
    if (HAutoproteccion.Checked == true){
        SelectQuery sQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", "Domain='"
                            + System.Environment.UserDomainName.ToString() + "'");
        // Ve los usuarios habilitados
        ManagementObjectSearcher mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sQuery);
        string userName= System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        foreach (ManagementObject mObject in mSearcher.Get()){
            userName = userName.Substring(userName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            if (mObject["Name"].ToString() == userName){
                DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
                string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + userName;
                myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Deny));
                myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
            }
        }
   } else {
       SelectQuery sQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount", "Domain='"
                            + System.Environment.UserDomainName.ToString() + "'");
       ManagementObjectSearcher mSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sQuery);
       string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
       foreach (ManagementObject mObject in mSearcher.Get()){
           userName = userName.Substring(userName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
           if (mObject["Name"].ToString() == userName){
               DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
               DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
               string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + userName;
               myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.Write, AccessControlType.Allow));
               myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

El punto es que sin los permisos escribe perfecto pero con los permisos ni siquiera a la aplicación la deja escribir, alguna ayuda?

Comment: La aplicación al ser ejecutada accede a las carpetas con tu usuario, por tanto si le has denegado el acceso no podrá acceder. Otra cosa es que ejecutes el programa como Administrador o como otro usuario.

Comment: ya edite el manifesto para que se ejecute como administrador y tenga permisos de administrador pero pasa lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres acceder a una ubicacion de red dentro de tu dominio, puedes hacer:

```
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(username, pass, domain);
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(@"\\server", nc, "Basic", nc);
string[] carpetas = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories("@\\server\share");
```